# How do I get chrome.tabs.insertCSS to work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I've been making a random fun chrome extension, and I've been trying to get chrome.tabs.insertCSS to work but it just won't. chrome.tabs.executeScript works fine, but insertCSS will not. This is what I have right now:

```
var txt = document.querySelector('#datapodtxt');
var img = document.querySelector('#datapodimg');
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"},function() {
    if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
        txt.innerText = "Error with page";
        img.src=chrome.extension.getURL('datapodblocked.jpg');
    } else {
        txt.innerText = "Datpodified your page";
                img.src=chrome.extension.getURL('datapod.jpg');
    }
});
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: "inject.css"});
```

It's just the last line which won't work, and I've tried a number of different things, but nothing happens.
(all that inject.css is in case you need it):

```
body {
  background-image: url("datapod.jpg") !important;
}
```

Comment: The page probably has its own CSS rule for the background image. Add `!important` before `;` in your CSS code.

Comment: @wOxxOm It doesn't work, even if the page has no background image, and `!important` doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Ah, I wasn't paying attention. You inject the image so you need to declare the image in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and [use a full URL in CSS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n) e.g. url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/datapod.jpg")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out that injecting a file doesn't work. Instead I can use code:

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {code: "body{background-image: url(\"datapod.jpg\") !important;}"});
```